# After using $.publish to load a select, want to select particular option in Struts 2 select tag

Tags: jquery, struts2, publish-subscribe

I am using `$.publish` to populate the dropdown (Struts 2 select tag) after that, I want the dropdown to be auto-selected to a value.

I tried the following:

```js
$.publish("reloadAttributeList");
        //$('#selectedAttribute option[value="attributeId"]');
        $('#selectedAttribute').val(attributeId).change();
        //$('#selectedAttribute').val(attributeId);
```

None worked.

Comment: Did you call it right after the publish?

Comment: Yes! I wanted in the same flow. Is it possible to auto select the drop down after the using publish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, after using `$.publish()` you can't auto select the drop down. The code to auto select dropdown should be inside the `$.subscribe()`. Some another event you should publish when loading is complete.

```jsp
<script>
  $.subscribe('loadCompleteAttributeList', function(event, data) {
    $('#selectedAttribute').val(attributeId);
  });
</script>
```